# I am confused on why my program wont display the output of my removing vowels from a string code

Tags: c++

Hi so I am creating a little program with the substr function to remove all vowels from a string and I thought I did it right but it wont show on the output. Sorry I am new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char ch);

string removeVowel(string str, char ch);

int main()
{
    string str;
    string str2;
    char ch;
    string newstr;

    getline(cin, str);

    newstr = removeVowel(str, ch);
    cout << newstr;

    return 0;
}
bool isVowel(char ch)

{
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

string removeVowel(string str, char ch)
{
    string newstr = " ";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++);
    if (isVowel(str[ch]))
        newstr = newstr + str.substr(ch, 1);
    while (i < str.length())

        return newstr;
}
```

Comment: At first glance `removeVowel` function seems to have some probllems, the for loop has a semi-colon at the end rendering it useless, `while (i < str.length()) return newstr;` also looks strange.

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of the for loop in `removeVowel` which shouldn't be there. The function `isVowel` returns true for a vowel character so you should check for false before appending the character to the new string. You are using `ch` instead of `i` inside the for loop.

Comment: It seems that you never initialize `ch`.

Comment: `while (i < str.length()) return newstr;` is quite odd. Remember in `c++` the first time you hit a return the function returns. It does not make any sense to have a loop. the `while (i < str.length())` part probably should be deleted.

Comment: @drescherjm okay but im trying to take all the vowels out of the string so how would I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

Your entire `removeVowel()` function is coded incorrectly, I see several mistakes in it:

- taking an input parameter `char ch` that is not actually useful for anything.
- initializing `newstr` with `" "`, rather than using `""`, or just leaving the initial value off completely and letting `std::string`'s default constructor handle the initialization.
- using `int` for the loop counter, rather than using `std::string::size_type` (which is what `str.length()` actually returns).
- terminating the loop prematurely with an erroneous `;`.
- using `ch` instead of `i` when accessing characters in `str`.
- using a useless `while` loop.

This function needs to be completely re-written from scratch.  Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char ch);
string removeVowels(string str);

int main()
{
    string str;
    string newstr;

    getline(cin, str);

    newstr = removeVowels(str);
    cout << newstr;

    return 0;
}

bool isVowel(char ch)
{
    return (
        ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' ||
        ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U'
    );
}

string removeVowels(string str)
{
    string newstr;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = str[i];
        if (!isVowel(ch))
            newstr += ch;
    }

    /* alternatively:
    for (char ch : str) {
        if (!isVowel(ch))
            newstr += ch;
    }
    */

    return newstr;
}
```

That being said, I would suggest a different implementation - using the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::string removeVowels(std::string str);

int main()
{
    std::string str, newstr;

    std::getline(cin, str);

    newstr = removeVowels(str);
    std::cout << newstr;

    return 0;
}

std::string removeVowels(std::string str)
{
    str.erase(
        std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
            [](char ch){
                ch = static_cast<char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));
                return (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u');
            }
        ),
        str.end()
    );
    return str;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to use `substr`, even though it is not the appropriate function for this exercise.
This can be achieved with `newstr += str.substr(i, 1)` but it is overkill.

Comment: Thanks! Thats amazing! i understand more because I thought I would need the ch from isVowel in the place of i

Comment: @tboschi "*even though it is not the appropriate function for this exercise*" - agreed, it is needless overhead to allocate a whole new temporary `std::string` for each `char`.